# Submit a jQuery array to Django view

Tags: jquery, arrays, django

I am new to Javascript and jQuery, and I'm trying to make a webpage which requires to pass/submit a JS array to Django view. Here is some sample code:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="title" value="title"/>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Get Custom Library!" /> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
         $("#myform").submit(function(){
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "loadURL", // Which URL should I post it to, if the URL is
                                 // dynamically generated?
                 data: {"arr[]": arr}
             });
         })
     });
 </script>
```

Django view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def form_submission(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_arr = request.POST.getlist('arr[]')
        return HttpResponse(','.join(my_arr))
```

But now it seems The Django view is not getting the array 'arr' anyways. Can anyone help fix the code above? This will be my life saver! Thanks a ton!!!

Also, in my app, the URL is dynamically generated. Which URL should I POST it to?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put ; after declaring array. Please replace the script

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
     $("#myform").submit(function(){
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "loadURL", // Which URL should I post it to, if the URL is
                             // dynamically generated?
             data: {"arr[]": arr}
         });
     })
 });
```